# find anagrams in a list of string using recursive solution in python

Tags: python, recursion, variable-assignment, anagram

I am trying to solve the following problem: there is a list like the below:

```py
["hi", "ih", "ciao", "aoic", "bar", "foo", "rab", "oof"]
```

And after being passed to a function, the list should be reduced to only those elements which first appear in the list, excluding all their anagrams after them.

so it should output:

```py
["hi", "ciao", "bar", "foo"]
```

I am trying to solve this recursively, and have the current solution, which breaks because of a "referenced before assignment" error on the variable result (last return stmt).

I am very grateful for any hint!

```py
def f(ls):
        
    def is_not_ana(first, word):
        return not sorted(first) == sorted(word) and word or None
    
    if ls:
        first = ls[0]
        rest = ls[1:]
        legal_str = [is_not_ana(first, word) for word in rest]
        result = list(filter(None, [first] + legal_str))
        
        return f(result[1:])
    else:
        return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach the end of your recursive, `ls` is empty, so when you return `result`, it is never defined in this last call.

You forgot to return the `first`. Change `return f(result[1:])` to `return [first] + f(result[1:])`.

Return an empty list will fix your error:

```py
def f(ls):
    def is_not_ana(first, word):
        return not sorted(first) == sorted(word) and word or None

    if ls:
        first = ls[0]
        rest = ls[1:]
        legal_str = [is_not_ana(first, word) for word in rest]
        result = list(filter(None, [first] + legal_str))

        return [first] + f(result[1:])
    else:
        return []


print(f(["hi", "ih", "ciao", "aoic", "bar", "foo", "rab", "oof"]))
# ['hi', 'ciao', 'bar', 'foo']
```